# Which credentials should I choose and how?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I want to use Google Drive API, Sheet API, Gmail API in my Python program.

I follow [this](https://socraticowl.com/post/integrate-google-sheets-and-jupyter-notebooks/) page. It says

"**Create credentials to use the Google Drive API**

After Enabling the Google Drive API, Google should take you to the Google Drive API console for your project.

Click **Create credentials.**"

It will create credentials for using only Drive? I read a lot of docs, official, blogs, tutorials, etc. I'm beginner in this topic, so please give some details also, because not everything is clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four types of credentials and they are used for different purposes and require different code to use them.

- Browser credentials used for applications which will be hosted on a website. For use with accessing private user data.
- Native credentials (other) used for installed applications. ex: A windows desktop application. For use with accessing private user data.
- Service account credentials used for server to server communication where the developer has access to the account which will be accessing the API.
- Mobile applications.

The first thing you need to do is decide whose data you will be accessing.  Are you expecting to access a users data then you will need to use OAuth2 and request the users permission to access the data.   If you are acting a static drive account and only that account and you personal have access to set it up you could use a service account.

**Browser credentials**

Uses OAuth2 to request permission of a user to access their data. Response will be returned to a web site. [web app sample](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app)

**Native credentials**

Use OAuth2 to request permission of a user to access their data. Response will be returned to the host where it was sent from. [installed app](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app)

**Service account credentials**

Service accounts are dummy users which we as developers can use to pre-authorize a user with access.  This method will not require user sign-in or consent.  [service account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts)

**Note**

You will probably only need to create one credential type.  You will need to enable all of the APIs you intend to use in the Google Developer Console.  (Google Drive API, Sheet API, Gmail API)  You should know that service accounts do not support gmail API unless you have a GSuite account and can set up the authorization.

You will need to create a service for each of the API types.

```
drive = build('drive', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
sheets = build('sheets', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
gmail = build('gmail', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. (I'm not so beginner :-) ) Reading your answer and rethinking what I want, Service account credentials is needed for me (it was my guess, but I wasn't sure).
Considering your **Note**, you are right, I forgot to say that I want to handle my own gmail messages. I think it is possible with restrictions, Gmail API can be used for free https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota.

Comment: Yes but you cant use a service account with the Gmail api unless you have gusite.  Your going to have to use Oauth2 it.  Your other apis will work fine with a service account.   (beginner level: its a very good question so i took the time to give some detailed information for beginners in the future this was no reflection on you)

Comment: (Yes, I think your answer will indeed helps other beginners also.) Yes, I intend to use Oauth2. The process of authentication is a little bit complex.

Comment: Let me know if i can help anymore.  I am not a python dev but am happy to help.   If the answer helped you also remember to accept it.